# How to create new lines above with vba if a condition is met?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet such that I want to create new rows above accordingly with data size in the column D (that goes as multiples of 17)

```
Option Explicit

Sub create_newlines()

Dim lastRow As Long

Dim x As Integer
Dim k As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim count As Integer



Range("D1").Select
lastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row


For i = 1 To lastRow


k = Len(Cells(4, i))
If k \ 17 > 1 Then
While count <= k \ 17
***here goes something that creates new blank lines above while the counter is less than the interger k\17**
count = count +1
Wend
       
Next

End Sub
```

After that, it would be interesting if it could copy the entire row to the new blank left spaces. Unfortunately my VBA is kinda rusty and I need help about what to use in the while loop and about the afterwards goal to paste the data of the row.

If someone can spot some mistake, I would like to know. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "data size in the column D" (`Len` counts the length of a string, not data)? Please *edit* some example data to make this understandable. Furthermore there's a missing `End If` in your code.

Comment: go from the bottom to the top `For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1` and simply use `Rows(i).Insert`, 
P.S. k = Len(Cells(4, i)) will not work.... maybe `k = Len(Range("D" & i).Value)`, - but I cannot catch the idea of this one. (breakfast, no time)